# What's a good way to deal with permissions with automated deployments across domains?

Tags: security, automation, nant

I have been working to automate some deployment processes using just Nant for the time being.  Once the Nant script scripts are fairly stable and proven, I'll be looking to incorporate CruiseControl.net or similar product.

With that being said, I ran into a snag today.

I have a Nant script that will copy files from a network share that is used as a staging area to the destination (very simple to start out with). In my snag today, I was attempting to copy the files to another file share that was on a separate domain.  The two domains do now have any trust between them.

The user running the Nant script had accessed both locations via Windows Explorer first to ensure that he had an authenticated session with both domains.  When he ran the script, he of course got an access denied error since Nant.exe was running under the credentials of the other domain.  This was an oversight on my part.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to address this issue without touching AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way that I can think of without touching AD that wouldn't be a hack. The right way to do it is to setup a service account in the domain where the nant job is running that has rights in the other domain. Then have the nant job run under the service account. The only hacky way that I can think of is to find a way to have the user with rights in both domains kick off the nant job and I'm not even positive that that would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather hacky, but you could have a NAnt task plug in the credentials for the foreign share, either by P/Invoking [`WNetUseConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385482(VS.85).aspx) or by issuing a command like

```
net use \\host\share password /user:user@domain
```

before copying the files across.